# Grid system using inline-block column and remove html white space with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, removing-whitespace

I have written a like-bootstrap CSS grids system, but i used inline-block instead left-floated block. Of course, I need a trick to remove white space between inline-block columns. And I also wrote a small pure-javascript to do that:

```
bodyzzz = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
bodyzzz.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace(/>\s*\n*\r*\</g, '><');
```

I know some other trick can remove white space, but they still have bugs (or weak points). So, for anyone expert in front-end dev, what's my trick's weak points? Do you guys think this solution is the best?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the space is due to that newline character when placing one div below the other

here is a way to get rid of the spaces

snippet

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  border:solid;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:none;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
Content1
</div><div>
Content2
</div><div>
Content3
</div>
```

Notice how the the starting div tags are on the same line as that of their preceeding div tag endings

**Edit: A much nicer is by setting css display to `display:table-cell;`**

here is another snippet

```css
div {
  display:table-cell;
  border:solid;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:none;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
Content1
</div>
<div>
Content2
</div>
<div>
Content3
</div>
```

Comment: Tks, Sir. But I use sublime text and Beautify plugin to write html, your way make the code look bad. It's better when we let javascript do the work. I realize if the webpage have content of html code inside, my trick'll break that content.

Comment: I understand :D....answer edited to style with display:table-cell which avoid having that ugly format

Comment: I see. But I'm working with inline-block, it's the most powerfull tool for web layout (compatibility, align left-right, aign center, reverse order,.... ). I'm wondering what is it effect to web performance, or something hard to identify.

Comment: btw, i realize my trick doesn't break the content if it's inside pre tags :D

Comment: my trick run after the html loaded, so we'll see it snap from sugly page (still have white space) to a  nicer page (white space removed), this is fast but it's still visible. A better solution is set font size of the wrapper to 0.001px, and reset it to 16px on inner elements !